# Como resolver erro de tamanho de memória para grandes arquivos gerados com o DomPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

O que acontece é que quando o HTML (gerado dinamicamente) fica muito grande, o pdf não é criado, e retorna este erro:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 64 bytes) in
>   /home/www/models/dompdf/include/frame_factory.cls.php on line 51.

Isso só acontece quando o arquivo do HTML fica bem grande, caso contrário é gerado normalmente. O HTML é baseado no [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), e tem alguns painéis, navtabs etc. O DomPDF ignora estas tags, mas fiquei pensando se não poderia ser por isso...

Já tentei [algumas soluções que encontrei no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml), tais como:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

ini_set ( 'memory_limit', '128M');
```

Isso eu fiz no arquivo que gera o PDF, porque não tenho acesso ao `php.ini`, e não sei como fazer no htaccess (algumas respostas no SO sugerem que mude no htaccess se o server permitir)... Mas nada resolveu até agora.

Esse é o arquivo `frame_factory.cls.php` (a linha 51 está marcada dentro do snippet):

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package dompdf
 * @link    http://www.dompdf.com/
 * @author  Benj Carson <benjcarson@digitaljunkies.ca>
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @version $Id: frame_factory.cls.php 470 2012-02-06 19:36:13Z fabien.menager $
 */

/**
 * Contains frame decorating logic
 *
 * This class is responsible for assigning the correct {@link Frame_Decorator},
 * {@link Positioner}, and {@link Frame_Reflower} objects to {@link Frame}
 * objects.  This is determined primarily by the Frame's display type, but
 * also by the Frame's node's type (e.g. DomElement vs. #text)
 *
 * @access private
 * @package dompdf
 */
class Frame_Factory {

  /**
   * Decorate the root Frame
   * 
   * @param $root Frame The frame to decorate
   * @param $dompdf DOMPDF The dompdf instance
   * @return Page_Frame_Decorator
   */
  static function decorate_root(Frame $root, DOMPDF $dompdf) {
    $frame = new Page_Frame_Decorator($root, $dompdf);
    $frame->set_reflower( new Page_Frame_Reflower($frame) );
    $root->set_decorator($frame);
    return $frame;
  }

  /**
   * Decorate a Frame 
   * 
   * @param $root Frame The frame to decorate
   * @param $dompdf DOMPDF The dompdf instance
   * @return Frame_Decorator
   * FIXME: this is admittedly a little smelly...
   */ 
  static function decorate_frame(Frame $frame, DOMPDF $dompdf) {
    if ( is_null($dompdf) )
      throw new Exception("foo");
      
    $style = $frame->get_style();
    
    switch ($style->display) { */----- LINHA 51 ------- */
      
    case "block":
      $positioner = "Block";        
      $decorator = "Block";
      $reflower = "Block";
      break;
    
    case "inline-block":
      $positioner = "Inline";
      $decorator = "Block";
      $reflower = "Block";
      break;

    case "inline":
      $positioner = "Inline";
      if ( $frame->is_text_node() ) {
        $decorator = "Text";
        $reflower = "Text";
      } 
      else {
        if ( DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT && $style->float !== "none" ) {
          $decorator = "Block";
          $reflower = "Block";
        }
        else {
          $decorator = "Inline";
          $reflower = "Inline";
        }
      }
      break;   

    case "table":
      $positioner = "Block";
      $decorator = "Table";
      $reflower = "Table";
      break;
      
    case "inline-table":
      $positioner = "Inline";
      $decorator = "Table";
      $reflower = "Table";
      break;

    case "table-row-group":
    case "table-header-group":
    case "table-footer-group":
      $positioner = "Null";
      $decorator = "Table_Row_Group";
      $reflower = "Table_Row_Group";
      break;
      
    case "table-row":
      $positioner = "Null";
      $decorator = "Table_Row";
      $reflower = "Table_Row";
      break;

    case "table-cell":
      $positioner = "Table_Cell";
      $decorator = "Table_Cell";
      $reflower = "Table_Cell";
      break;
        
    case "list-item":
      $positioner = "Block";
      $decorator  = "Block";
      $reflower   = "Block";
      break;

    case "-dompdf-list-bullet":
      if ( $style->list_style_position === "inside" )
        $positioner = "Inline";
      else        
        $positioner = "List_Bullet";

      if ( $style->list_style_image !== "none" )
        $decorator = "List_Bullet_Image";
      else
        $decorator = "List_Bullet";
      
      $reflower = "List_Bullet";
      break;

    case "-dompdf-image":
      $positioner = "Inline";
      $decorator = "Image";
      $reflower = "Image";
      break;
      
    case "-dompdf-br":
      $positioner = "Inline";
      $decorator = "Inline";
      $reflower = "Inline";
      break;

    default:
      // FIXME: should throw some sort of warning or something?
    case "none":
      $positioner = "Null";
      $decorator = "Null";
      $reflower = "Null";
      break;
    }

    // Handle CSS position
    $position = $style->position;
    
    if ( $position === "absolute" )
      $positioner = "Absolute";

    else if ( $position === "fixed" )
      $positioner = "Fixed";
      
    // Handle nodeName
    $node_name = $frame->get_node()->nodeName;
    
    if ( $node_name === "img" ) {
      $style->display = "-dompdf-image";
      $decorator = "Image";
      $reflower = "Image";
    }
  
    $positioner .= "_Positioner";
    $decorator .= "_Frame_Decorator";
    $reflower .= "_Frame_Reflower";

    $deco = new $decorator($frame, $dompdf);
    $deco->set_positioner( new $positioner($deco) );
    $reflow = new $reflower($deco);
    
    $deco->set_reflower( $reflow );
    
    return $deco;
  }
}
```

Comment: Quando isso acontecia comigo, tinha pensando na estratégia de carregar o conteúdo sobre demanda (como se fosse uma paginação) e ir gerando os pdfs numa pasta temporária. Depois passa o link para download, ou qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: Não sei se entendi @WallaceMaxters... é um pdf só, que é gerado através de um HTML buscado no bd (o usuário gravou este HTML no bd quando gerou um resultado, e daí pego ele com uma query sql pra colocar dentro da template do DomPDF)... Vc quer dizer pra gravar o pdf antes da requisição do usuário, e deixar ele numa pasta né, passando só o link ao invés de gerar na hora da requisição... mas isso  faria gastar menos memória?  Quer dizer, não vai dar o mesmo problema? Valeu...

Comment: Ja tive este mesmo problema quando eu ia gerar grandes relatórios. Minha solução foi abandonar o html e fazer na mão mesmo o layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repare o seguinte, o erro informa que você precisa de mais de 134MB de memória para funcionar e o máximo que você definiu foi 128MB. Tente colocar mais memória e verifique:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Tem que saber também se o servidor suporta essa configuração.

Comment: Então, eu testei até com mais, acho que o problema pode ser que o servidor não aceita mesmo... Mandei uma mensagem pra eles, vms ver... +1 Valeu por enquanto.

Comment: Ok Gustavo, se for hospedagem compartilhada pode ser que não funcione mesmo, teria que partir para vps ou dedicado. Mas talvez eles deem uma solução alternativa. Sucesso!

Comment: Era isso mesmo (configuração do servidor), e a única forma de mudar é passar pra um plano mais caro. :/